# Как подключиться к сайту с пк, который находится на этом же пк?

Tags: сервер, gitlab, доступ

Я установил GitLab сервер на свой пк, направил домен `gitlab.example.com` на ip адрес сети `12.123.22.13`. Из любой другой сети подключение к `gitlab.example.com:50443` или `12.123.22.13:50443`работает, но если я пытаюсь подключиться с того же компьютера, на котором этот сервер находится, то ничего не выходит. Порт `50443` проброшен на мой пк в локальной сети.

Я пробовал подключаться через `gitlab.example.com:50443`, `192.168.0.123:50443` и `12.123.22.13:50443` - результата нет. Если я включаю VPN, то подключение работает нормально, но такой способ неудобнен.

Comment: В [hosts](https://help.reg.ru/support/dns-servery-i-nastroyka-zony/rabota-s-dns-serverami/fayl-hosts-gde-nakhoditsya-i-kak-yego-izmenit) прописано `12.123.22.13 gitlab.example.com` ?